# Python: How to build a dictionary with multiple slip strings

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, html-parsing, mechanize

In my admin page I have a list of usernames and IDs. I'm trying to build a dictionary to use it later to automate some jobs.
The code that I've build is:

```
def nameID_tag(src):
    nameID = {}
    try:
        id = src.split('<option value="')[1].split('" >')[0]
        names = src.split(id+'\" >')[1].split('</option>')[0]
        nameID[names] = id
    except:
        print "Could not retrieve data."
    return nameID
```

The HTML code:

```
<option value="1" >admin</option>
<option value="2" >viktor</option>
<option value="3" >ana</option>
```

Then I call it:

```
s=br.open(url).read()
nameID_tag(s)
```

Its working fine for 1 user, but don't know how to get all the users+ids and build the dictionary.

Comment: What is the content of `s`?

Comment: s - is a html page (admin page with user+ids) that I read for parsing

Comment: I suppose I meant "could you post the content of the string `s` so I can see how it's structured", but you have an answer already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, i'm pretty bad with regular expressions. So there's probably better ways to do this. But this seems to work

```
import re

IDs = re.findall('(?<=<option value=")\w+', html)
names = re.findall('(?<=>)\w+(?=</option>)', html)
nameID =  dict(zip(IDs,names))
```